# setInterval not firing after orientation change iOS 6

Tags: javascript, ios, setinterval

Hi I have a problem with setInterval on ipads and iphones running javascript. Is there a fix for this?

I can see the console log increment but after orientation change it stops.

```
    var x = 0;
    var testInterval = setInterval(function(){console.log(x); x++;}, 100);
```

Comment: What version of iOS 6? Is it below iOS 6.1? (iOS 6.0/6.0.1)?

Comment: I ask because there was a nasty bug that affected iOS 6.0-6.0.2 with regard to timers (both setInterval, setTimeout). There are a couple workarounds available [here](https://gist.github.com/ronkorving/3755461) and [here](https://gist.github.com/jpattishall/4180482) (full disclosure, I wrote the second one). I'm curious if maybe you're running into this problem? If you're interested in trying my workaround, it requires just passing a third argument, true, in your setInterval. If THAT works, then you're being hit with the timer bug.

Comment: I'm using iOS 6.1.3 (10B329) on an iPad 2. The timer bug still affects my site.

Comment: Oh wow, that's really interesting! Did either one of the workarounds I link to work for you?

Comment: Looks to me a youtube iframe player is causing the problem. everytime the youtube video plays and I change orientation all timers stop. Even timers from different scripts in the page stops. Anyone encountered this problem? When I remove the player all timers work okay.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. CSS media queries is resizing the youtube iframe and when it does the setInterval doesn't work inside onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() anymore. I don't know why it only affects iOS 6.Putting the timer outside means you cannot target the yt player because it creates a new instance everytime the iframe resizes on orientation change.